# Windows TTS voices with Festival in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, text-to-speech, festival

I am looking to programatically generate text to speech wave files on my Ubuntu box and the Festival and Text2Wave tools in Ubuntu seem to do a pretty good job of this, except for the generally poor voices and lack of accents.

The only TTS I can find with Australian accents are the Realspeak voices Lee and Karen.  I have these files in the format which they can be loaded into TextAloud on Windows, but I wonder if there is any way of making it work with Festival or another command line linux tool.

Answer (score 0):

Best option seems to be http://code.google.com/p/open-sapi/.

So far is not stable and otherwise using the SAPI5 in Linux does not seem possible at this point in time.